# Conversion formula between multidimensional Ito and Stratonovich SDEs

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Does anyone on here know of a reference that explicitly computes a conversion formula between the drift terms in multidimensional Ito and Stratonovich SDEs?

In particular, given a solution $(X_t)$ of an N-dimensional Stratonovich SDE
$$
dX_t=b(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)\circ dB_t
$$
what is the drift term $\tilde{b}(X_t)$ that makes $(X_t)$ a solution of the Ito SDE
$$
dX_t=\tilde{b}(X_t)dt+\sigma(X_t)dB_t
$$

I've found one online reference so far (http://www.performancetrading.it/Documents/KsStrong/KsS_Conversion.htm), although there is no derivation here and I will not go to the length of actually deriving this myself. I need to cite this result, so a book, paper etc. would be excellent.

P.S.: The conversion formula should be multidimensional. I do of course know the 1-dimensional conversion which is quoted in most standard texts.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reference for the multidimensional Itô-Stratonovich conversion: [pages 137 and 138](https://books.google.nl/books?id=_WfwCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137) of *Theory and Numerics of Differential Equations*, by James Blowey, John P. Coleman, Alan W. Craig (Springer, 2013).